# not able to render my react component in redux way

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react.
- I am trying to display a component.
- but right now I am getting an error
- so I debugged and commented the app.
- but still I am facing an error.
- can you tell me how to fix so that infuture I will fix it myself
- providing my code snippet and stackblitz code below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zm9t65?file=components%2FApp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import LoadingBar from "react-redux-loading-bar";

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { logger } from 'redux-logger'
import reducer from './reducers'
//import App from "./components/App"

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  //  <App />
             <LoadingBar />

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: no error is shown and no error posted here ..fix your questions first else it will be marked negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your code but in your comment statement.

`//` is not jsx comment statement. `{/* ... */}` is jsx comment.

Change your code to

index.js

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App>
       <LoadingBar />
    </App>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <div> Hello World
    {/* < RecentChannelItem />
    < ChannelsField />
    <Button />
    <TopNews /> */}
  </div>
)
export default App;
```

Comment: hey I updated the code but still I dont see the loading bar...providing my updated code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zm9t65?file=components%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `App` and `LoadingBar` as children to `Provider` because it expects to have only one child which is surely your `App` component, actually this is not a proper place to add the `LoadingBar` at all.

I just modified `index.js` to be as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import LoadingBar from "react-redux-loading-bar";

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { logger } from 'redux-logger'
import reducer from './reducers'
import App from "./components/App"

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

`App.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
// import ChannelsField from './ChannelsField'
// import RecentChannelItem from './RecentChannelValues'

// import Button from '../containers/Button'
// import TopNews from '../containers/TopNews'
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1> Hello </h1>
  </div>
)
export default App;
```

And the component is rendered and I can see Hello.

Usually elements like `LoadingBar` are used inside your components to be displayed when you are waiting for asynchronous tasks to complete (for example fetching data from API)

So I suggest importing it using `import` statement inside `App` (or any other component) and use it.

Comment: I used in my fetchapi i was not successful...so I tried in this type of small stackblitz....providing my api code here where I used the loading bar component... my code is in RecipeReviewCardList.js and method name is getPlayerssData...can you tell me how to fix it
https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp